# Escaping Special character

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I am inserting data in mysql table , prior to that i am escape sequencing variable

```
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data);
```

Every thing is working fine , but when i am getting data like this

```
$data = " SHR′ n(X′) ";
```

its escaping  data like this

```
SHRâ€² n(Xâ€²)
```

which is not inserting in database and giveing error, So my question is how can i make it to escape this kind of characters.

Note:I have created a table with `utf8_general_ci`  as collation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

after establish connection use

```
mysqli_set_charset ($con, "utf8");
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not helping in insertion , still some random character s are coming after escaping

Answer (score 1):

Try to [set the charset to utf8](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php).

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");
/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem continues same here

Comment: Where does the value from `$data` come from? Is it in your php file or a html form or something else? Is the source utf8, too? do you save your php file as utf8 without bom?

Comment: The data is coming from excel sheet and that sheet is saved with UTF8_encoded format

Comment: How do you read the data from the excel sheet? Is your php file encoded with utf8 without bom?